# Compare two dataframe and update a column in first dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have two dataframes: `df1` and `df2`. `df1` has columns `id` and `name`. `df2` has `id` and `firstname`. I want to compare all `id` of a `df1` with `id` present in `df2` and for matches, want to update/overwrite `firstname` column by the value of `name` column in `df1`.

The code I tried is:

```
df1.loc[df1.id.isin(df2.id),[name]]= df2[[firstname]].values
```

Comment: HI welcome to SO. Please read something about [mcve](/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You can define a series mapping and then use [`pd.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
id_name_map = df2.set_index('id')['firstname']
df1['name'] = df1['id'].map(id_name_map).fillna(df1['name'])
```

Or if you need to do this the other way round:

```
id_name_map = df1.set_index('id')['name']
df2['firstname'] = df2['id'].map(id_name_map).fillna(df2['firstname'])
```

In each case, we use `fillna` to ensure `id`s which do not match do not cause names to be overwritten.